# Output Kentico 8 page content to xml feed

Tags: asp.net, kentico

Is there a way to output page content to xml feed (just page content , no master page)? I want to output the rendered content from repeaters and editable text components (basically everything within the page placeholder for a certain page). Something like this:
www.site.com/page/xml   (In this case the xml will be the feed of everything from the /page/).

I tried using Documents DataSource for the page (menu item), but couldn't render its content..

Comment: sounds nice! I am no expert in kentico 8, but i think you would have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of "syndication" web parts in Kentico 8, which could fit your scenario.
There are basically two categories of syndication web parts - repeaters and feeds.

- repeaters - web parts supposed to be used along with various data source web parts
- feeds - web parts pre-configured for the most common scenarios

Try connecting the **XML Repeater** to the **Documents data source**.

If you need examples see Corporate sample site (Special Pages -> RSS -> ...).
Examples of transformations can be found under the "cms.root" document type.

If you need any further information see the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Setting+up+syndication+feeds).

Comment: This method only works with repeaters.. not editable text webpart .. or all webparts on the specific page